# I cant change the brand name for total product

Tags: sql, olap-cube

i cant seem to change the brand name for total product example is Apple to Grand Total for Apple

I am having a problem with my code this is my code

```
SELECT Month(PurchaseDate) AS 'Month',CASE
WHEN GROUPING(Brand) = 0 THEN Brand 
When GROUPING(MONTH(PurchaseDate)) = 1 THEN 'Grand Total' 
When GROUPING(Brand) = 1 THEN 'Monthly SubTotal' END AS 'Brand', 
SUM(PRICE) AS 'Total Amount' 
FROM [Purchase_Items]
GROUP BY MONTH(PurchaseDate),Brand with CUBE
```

`This is the output:`
`[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5lJO.png)`

`But this is what i expected to be output:`
`[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtQwh.png)`

`Pls help me`

Comment: use the following `When GROUPING(MONTH(PurchaseDate)) = 1 THEN 'Grand Total for ' + Brand ` in your 3rd line

Answer (score 0):

I amended line 3 and changed the statement to THEN 'Grand Total for ' + Brand. I then swapped line 2 and 3

Finally put in a CTE table to replace the Null with 'Grand Total'

The result is exactly what you got.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT Month(PurchaseDate) AS 'Month',
    CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(MONTH(PurchaseDate)) = 1 THEN 'Grand Total for ' + Brand 
        WHEN GROUPING(Brand) = 0 THEN Brand 
        WHEN GROUPING(Brand) = 1 THEN 'Monthly SubTotal'
    END AS 'Brand', 
    SUM(PRICE) AS 'Total Amount' 
FROM #total
GROUP BY MONTH(PurchaseDate),Brand with CUBE)

SELECT [Month],Isnull(Brand,'Grand Total'),[Total Amount]
FROM cte
```

[image: CTE Brand]